# How to change the host name from localhost to some ip in react js?

Tags: reactjs

Hi I want to change my loading of react in my local computer from localhost to some IP that matches my backend API, I tried all suggested options on the internet like using a proxy in package.json or using

```
 "scripts": {
    **"start": "HOST=http://127.0.0.1 react-scripts start",**
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

nothing working rather it's giving error like

```
(node:28360) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_AFTER_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onAfterSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:28360) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_BEFORE_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onBeforeSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
/media/as/Learn/Practice/Practice project/mern fulllstack/ECOMMERCE/frontend/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/lib/Server.js:2429
        throw error;
        ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http://127.0.0.1
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:71:26) {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'http://127.0.0.1'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! frontend@0.1.0 start: `HOST=http://127.0.0.1 react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the frontend@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/as/.npm/_logs/2022-07-23T05_00_21_832Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Hi. I don't quite understand the problem. Normally, when you run your react application locally it should also be available via the network IP in the form of 192.x.x.x. Try running ifconfig for windows or ifconfig on mac on your terminal.

Comment: No it's running in localhost:3000 , problem is that my backend node js application is running on 127.0.0.1:3000 and my react app is running in localhost:3000 , so when i call the api , it's showing error as the protocols are different

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing something like this yet:

```
"scripts": {
"protocol": "http://",
"host": "127.0.0.1",
"port": "80",
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
```

Comment: It's still running in localhost:3000

Comment: I'm going to submit a different kind of answer to the question and eventually delete this one :)

Answer (score 0):

Create an .env file in the project root and type

```
PORT=3000
HOST=127.0.0.1
```

Comment: That sounds like a really good answer :) Hopefully it works for their configuration!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

Click on the Start Menu Icon

Type:

```
cmd
```

Right click on:

```
cmd.exe
```

Click on:

```
Run as Administrator
```

A command prompt will appear.
In command prompt, type in:

```
notepad "C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts"
```

In the host file, Go to the line right underneath:

```
#   ::1             localhost"
```

And add this information

```
127.0.0.1    mynode
127.0.0.1    myreact
```

Click file, then click Save

Reboot the computer

Configure your node to use the hostname of:

```
mynode
```

Configure your react to use the hostname of:

```
myreact
```

Your url for a website connection will be http://mynode:3000 and http://myreact:3000

Answer (score 0):

Create .env file in project root

```bash
PORT=8080 # or other port
```

React app hosted on `localhost:PORT`

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration